# Imagefill javascript lagging

Tags: javascript, css, image

I'm using the plugin imagefill (http://johnpolacek.github.io/imagefill.js/).

You can see when the site loads it initially loads the image at the top then the plugin fires and the image repositions itself to where it should be. Any idea how i can get this happening as soon as the page loads without any lag?

I've tried to lower the resolution of the image down to 70kb but still happens so don't think it has anything to do with image size.

Code below...
Thanks!

Javascipt for imagefill

```
var $container = this,
    imageAspect = 1/1,
    containersH = 0,
    containersW = 0,
    defaults = {
      runOnce: false,
      target: 'img',
      throttle : 200  // 5fps
    },
    settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

var $img = $container.find(settings.target).addClass('loading').css({'position':'absolute'});

// make sure container isn't position:static
var containerPos = $container.css('position');
$container.css({'overflow':'hidden','position':(containerPos === 'static') ? 'relative' : containerPos});

// set containerH, containerW
$container.each(function() {
  containersH += $(this).outerHeight();
  containersW += $(this).outerWidth();
});

// wait for image to load, then fit it inside the container
$container.imagesLoaded().done(function(img) {
  imageAspect = $img.width() / $img.height();
  $img.removeClass('loading');
  fitImages();
  if (!settings.runOnce) {
    checkSizeChange();
  }
});

function fitImages() {
  containersH  = 0;
  containersW = 0;
  $container.each(function() {
    imageAspect = $(this).find(settings.target).width() / $(this).find(settings.target).height();
    var containerW = $(this).outerWidth(),
        containerH = $(this).outerHeight();
    containersH += $(this).outerHeight();
    containersW += $(this).outerWidth();

    var containerAspect = containerW/containerH;
    if (containerAspect < imageAspect) {
      // taller
      $(this).find(settings.target).css({
          width: 'auto',
          height: containerH,
          top:0,
          left:-(containerH*imageAspect-containerW)/2
        });
    } else {
      // wider
      $(this).find(settings.target).css({
          width: containerW,
          height: 'auto',
          top:-(containerW/imageAspect-containerH)/2,
          left:0
        });
    }
  });
}

function checkSizeChange() {
  var checkW = 0,
      checkH = 0;
  $container.each(function() {
    checkH += $(this).outerHeight();
    checkW += $(this).outerWidth();
  });
  if (containersH !== checkH || containersW !== checkW) {
    fitImages();
  }
  setTimeout(checkSizeChange, settings.throttle);
}

return this;
```

Function to run it - $('.header-image').imagefill();

Container it sits in - div class="header-image"

Css for header-image(before javascript styles get added) - height: 285px; overflow: hidden; margin-top: 170px;

Comment: it's using imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js and jquery-imagefill.js and getting executed by $('.header-image').imagefill();  -  this then works out centering the image based on the height(285px) and width (100%) of the container surrounding the image

Comment: ive add the appropriate code